# Links in Team Site Left Navigation Column Only Visible to Site Admins

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, left-navigation

I have a SharePoint Online Team Site with multiple links in the left navigation column that only the Site Administrators can see. The only customization on the site is a script editor web part setting a background image. Site Owners and Members only see the "Home" link in the navigation column. I've completed the following steps to resolve this issue.

1. Activated the Site Collection Features > SharePoint Sever Publishing Infrastructure and corresponding Site Actions > Manage Site Features > SharePoint Server Publishing features;
2. Verified the 'custom script' and Quick Launch settings are enabled; and
3. I've removed and re-created the navigation links.

Nothing has affected the visibility for Site members. Has anyone seen this happen before?

Thank you in advance for any assistance,
PLove

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your navigation settings and see if you have **[audience targeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-audience-targeting-in-modern-sharepoint-sites-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)** enabled for the links. This feature can be enabled for both *Quick Launch* when editing in modern experience, and *Structural Navigation* in Navigation Settings.

A few more things to check:

1. Do you see the same issue with publishing features deactivated, or in another team site?
2. The script editor web part should not cause this issue, but try removing it temporarily and then check the navigation again.

Comment: I discovered the issue and corrected it.  The links point to files moved to SharePoint from a different file server.  The document library had no permission settings and the permissions attached to the migrated files controlled access and subsequently the visibility of the links in the left navigation column.  Thank you for your time and response.

Comment: @PattiLove Thanks for sharing. I would suggest you post this solution as a new Answer and accept it to close this thread. It would help others too.